# How to output images using php?

Tags: php, gd

```
<?php
$f = new SaeFetchurl();
$img_data = $f->fetch( 'http://ss7.sinaimg.cn/bmiddle/488efcbbt7b5c4ae51ca6&690' );
$img = new SaeImage();
$img->setData( $img_data );
$img->resize(200); 
$img->flipH(); 
$img->flipV(); 
$new_data = $img->exec();
$img->exec( 'jpg' , true );

if ($new_data === false)
        var_dump($img->errno(), $img->errmsg());
?>
```

Here is the code from sina sae. It offers images service. When I paste the code on my page, I just can see the mess in the browser.

What does this "$img->exec( 'jpg' , true );" mean?

How to output the images using php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mess you mean a bunch of characters?

Try to set the header information

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: yes.I get a bunch of characters.I had try as your saying but it doesn't work. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The mess might be the interpreted image (code). You might want  to include the php script into the `src` attribute of an html image tag.

Like:

```
<img src="foobar.php?optional=params" />
```

Answer (score 0):

just adding on to Alex. I been using this over the past new days and I've noticed that my images will not be shown on the page without the extra 2 lines below.

```
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
```